# Talend Create Select Performance tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, talend, data-integration

I just realised that when I run a create select statement on my Oracle 11g database the execution is about three times faster than using Talend to select the data then creating and writing the data into the new table.

So I am wondering if there is a way to just connect to the database and run the create select query on the database in talend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to run the create-select query directly on the DB with the expected performance using the tDBRow for MySQL (formerly tMySQLRow) component as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

Use the tOracleInput component.

Copy the query into the query field, surround it in quotes and drop the semicolon so something like this:

"SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION_1"

Then hit the guess schema button

That will build the component schema based on your query.

Comment: Thanks @alex for responding. I don't want to get the shema at the level of talend. I want to create a table in the data base instead using the data selected from other tables. I realise it's at least 3 times faster when I do it using toad. So I want to acheive the same performance using Talend.